# How make a web service in Ruby that not kill process in background when response a client request?

Tags: ruby, web-services

I want to create a web service(Ruby 1.8.7) with a method service that allow me run some code that generate background process and not stop this after a while of method return. Previously I traying with the gem simplews but the process apparently stop after a while. Any answer, not only will be helpfully in matter of knowledge, but that is for my thesis and i have short time

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish your task simply using something such as Sinatra and running a background process.  First install Sinatra with `gem install sinatra`.  Then write a very simple ruby application like this example Sinatra app:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  %x["/my/background/process &"]
  "Started running background process!"
end
```

Now run the sinatra app with:

```
$ ruby myapp.rb
```

And then connect with your browser using the port number that Sinatra tells you:

```
http://127.0.0.1:4567/
```

The port number Sinatra uses for you might be different than 4567.  You should see "Started running background process!" in your browser and your background process should be running.